# Microsoft Access, autonumber with year prefix

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to create a table with a primary key.  That primary key should include the last two digits of the year and should be followed by a one-up (i.e., auto-incremented) number for that year.

For example, in 2014 I have 10 purchase orders, so the rows should reflect:
141, 142, ... 1410.
In year 2015, so far, I've had 67 purchase orders, so they should reflect:
151, 152, ... 1567.

How would I make the primary key include both the year and incremental number of that year?  It's important that each year returns to the incremental number of 1 and not where the previous year left off.  I wouldn't want 2015 to start off with 1511.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I won't give you a full coded answer as I don't really know how your DB looks, I would suggest the following:

- Create your table with an auto number type field say [Iteration]
- Create a calculated field that returns the year of the created date [FiscYear] using something like `Year(Date())`
- Create a select query that select the maximum value of [Iteration] for the previous fiscal year called [PrevTotal] who's single value is MaxOfIteration
  -Create a calculated field which is Cint([FiscYear] & ([Iteration] - [PrevTotal].[MaxOfIteration]))

Probably not the best answer but certainly the easiest I can think of.

EDIT: Occurs to me you might want to set the "Result Type" of the field to an integer or long etc.